# embedded element in xml literal query - child axis

Tags: vb.net, xml-literals

Is it possible to query an XML Literals statement with an embedded expression for the name of an XElement on a child axis?

For example, this works when using an extension method:

```
Dim clrValue As String = "green"
Dim el As XElement = Source...<clrScheme>.Elements(clrValue).FirstOrDefault
```

But as an embedded expression, it doesn't work:

```
Dim clrValue As String = "blue"
Dim el As XElement = Source...<clrScheme>.<<%= clrValue %>>.FirstOrDefault
```

The difference is `.Elements(clrValue).` vs `.<<%= clrValue %>>.`.
The IDE hover-over-`<<%...` errors I'm getting are:

1. XML Name Expected
2. '>' expected
3. Expression expected
4. Character is not valid

There is no documentation to say that I can use an embedded expression as an XElement name in a child axis, but there also isn't any document to say that I can't. Is this even possible and I'm just missing something, like a processing directive?

Comment: Do you want find element with given name by using XML axis properties?

Comment: Yes, as shown in the sample. In my actual final it will be one of 12 choices, of what the possible name can be. As there will be siblings to that element I need to target it directly. As you can see, I can already do this via an extension method, but I'm just looking to see how or if this can be done with a child axis property.

Comment: From docs: _Embedded expressions can appear **only** at certain locations within XML literal expressions_ - so you can create instance of `XElement` with name declared by embedded expression, but seems like axis properties do not support it.

Comment: I think XML Axis properties are compiler features. For example `document.<elementName>` will be mapped to the `document.Elements("elementName")` function. Because mapping happened during compile time - you not allowed to use run-time values